# Custom React start script for disabled same origin policy in Chrome

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, npm-scripts

Currently, I launch the react app with `npm start` which triggers the `react-scripts start` command in package.json.

This automatically launches the Chrome browser, which is great, but I need it to launch Chrome in *"disable web security"* mode.

This is done using this command:

```
open -n -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir="/tmp/chrome_dev_test" --disable-web-security
```

How can I enable this to run instead or standard chrome?

I've tried:

```json
"start": "BROWSER='open -n -a /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --args --user-data-dir='/tmp/chrome_dev_test' --disable-web-security' react-scripts start",
```

In my package.json scripts, but nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done like this in package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "start:dev": "npm run start:browser && npm run start",
    "start:browser": "open -n -a /Applications/Google\\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\\ Chrome --args --user-data-dir='/tmp/chrome_dev_test' --disable-web-security",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```